# IMAP search for non-ascii characters

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap, non-ascii-characters

What is the COMMAND used to search for non ascii or Japanese characters in IMAP GMAIL server?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to use a CHARSET UTF-8 SEARCH with a literal.  For example (each line ends with a \r\n):

```
> tag UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {4}
< + go ahead
> term
< * SEARCH 700 701 702
< tag OK SEARCH done
```

term should be UTF-8 encoded, and the 4 should be the length of the search therm, in bytes after encoding.

For example, to search for the term 日本 which is \xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC in UTF-8 encoding (6 bytes)

```
> tag UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {6}
< + go ahead
> <6 bytes of binary data>
< * SEARCH 700 701 702
< tag OK SEARCH done
```

You can use different search keys besides `TEXT`, such as `BODY` or `TO`.  Searching in utf-8 should work on any reasonable IMAP server.  Other character sets are less likely to be supported.

Comment: gmail supports rfc6855, so it's also possible to enable general UTF8  support ('tag enable utf8=accept') and then use UTF8-encoded text in plain strings: 'tag uid search body "日本"'.

Comment: Thanks for your usefull reply.I tried with this command by the following steps.Step 1: tag UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {6}\r\n step 2:i got +go ahead response from the server step 3 :after that i sent the encoded data like tag \xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC\r\n step 4: I got BAd command not parsed error

Comment: I am using Gmail IMAP server.Will it work on Gmail server also?

Comment: Yes, it will work on Gmail.  Please make sure you are sending exactly the six bytes, plus the crlf.  Do not send a tag for a literal continuation response.

Comment: Also make sure you have SELECTed a folder.

Comment: Hi Max,I have done this test after selected inbox folder.I sent the UTF-8 encoded binary data like this \xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC after recieved +go Ahead from server.But still i am getting Bad command could not parse error message.Please give the exact binary data format.I think i am send wrong binary data format

Comment: Send the actual utf-8 encoded bytes. That's a python style representation of the data. Send the bytes 0xE6, 0x97, etc. Or just take a string and encode it as utf-8, and make sure you set the literal length to the correct number.

Comment: Hi Max, can you please give me the actual UTF-8 format for this charcters 日本.So that, i can send the encoded string after +goAhead and let you know the result.I am still stuck on this issue

Comment: I gave you the six bytes it encoded to. I can't make it any clearer. It's up to you to encode those bytes in whatever language you are using.