# JavaMail. IMAP Search using a literal on Gmail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I need a help with next question:

I need to do a search using non-ascii characters on **Gmail** (*Cyrillic alphabet* (for example *Russian* or *Ukrainian*)). When I use the standard IMAP SEARCH command I receive an error:

```
A12 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 SUBJECT "текст" ALL
A12 BAD Could not parse command
```

In Java, it looks like

```
Message[] foundMessages = imapFolder.search(new SubjectTerm("текст"));
```

I've found some help here [IMAP search for non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502901/imap-search-for-non-ascii-characters). Using `openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993` I've connected to my mailbox via *Terminal* and I've received next results:

```
A12 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW {10}
+ go ahead
текст
* SEARCH 226
A13 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

The main question - How to implement this in Java?

**UPDATE**

I've done some research on JavaMail source code. I've found next lines

```
// if server supports UTF-8, enable it for client use
// note that this is safe to enable even if mail.mime.allowutf8=false
if (p.hasCapability("UTF8=ACCEPT") || p.hasCapability("UTF8=ONLY"))
    p.enable("UTF8=ACCEPT");
}
```

and from gmail server we receive next capabilities

```
A1 LOGIN test@gmail.com password
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN
X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH 
UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS 
LITERAL-SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
```

So, JavaMail sets `mail.mime.allowutf8` to `true` automatically. But in this case, JavaMail does a search using next command

```
C6 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW "текст" ALL
```

And I receive an error

```
C6 BAD Could not parse command
```

I've gone ahead and investigated 
https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/52e04fc107d0b83fa794e6f622f7c76b9e85e395/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/iap/Argument.java#L313

```
Argument.nastring(byte[] bytes, Protocol protocol, boolean doQuote)
```

boolean utf8 = protocol.supportsUtf8(); --> **For Gmail it's true**. That's why JavaMail doesn't use a literal.

```
byte b;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    b = bytes[i];
    if (b == '\0' || b == '\r' || b == '\n' ||
        (!utf8 && ((b & 0xff) > 0177))) {
    // NUL, CR or LF means the bytes need to be sent as literals
    literal(bytes, protocol);
    return;
    }
    if (b == '*' || b == '%' || b == '(' || b == ')' || b == '{' ||
        b == '"' || b == '\\' ||
        ((b & 0xff) <= ' ') || ((b & 0xff) > 0177)) {
    quote = true;
    if (b == '"' || b == '\\') // need to escape these characters
        escape = true;
    }
}
```

I've tested other email provider which doesn't have `UTF8=ACCEPT`. And all work fine.

```
K11 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 SUBJECT {10}
+ continue
текст ALL
* SEARCH 1194
K11 OK SEARCH completed
```

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look at the source, it ought to Just Work if you use javamail 1.6.1. You may want/need to set the `mail.mime.allowutf8` property to true.

In more detail: 1.6 adds support for unicode email addresses such as jøran@blåbærsyltetøy­.gulbrandsen.priv.no, which as a side effect regularises the use of UTF8 almost everywhere. When you connect to gmail, javamail 1.6 ought to send a login command, then automatically one along the lines of `a04 enable utf8=accept` and once gmail has acked utf8=accept, `a12 search subject "текст" all` becomes legal syntax that ought to do what you want.

Comment: I've tried your answer. But I still receive an error. `A1 OK user@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
a04 enable utf8=accept
* ENABLED UTF8=ACCEPT
a04 OK Success
a12 search subject "текст" all
a12 BAD SEARCH not allowed now.`

Comment: You'll find that search for "text" fails with the same error. You have to select a mailbox before you can search.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've forgotten to do `A5 SELECT INBOX`. Now your code are working